How to update React Native aars and pom in a project?
I am a total newbie to React native and have taken over a legacy native android project with a react native module inside it written 4 years ago. We have recently been receiving a lot of crash logs and also warnings by google that our current RN uses a very bad SoLoader version so I was trying to update the library. The folder structure is like this in the native project:

After searching on a lot of blogs and posts, I stumbled across this link and realized that the react native package used in our project is now in some other framework belonging to walmartlabs maven-repo.
Can someone explain what is this walmartlabs.ern and is it too different from the actual react native library provided by facebook. Also is it okay to still have this folder structure or should I remove these and use gradle dependency instead? This is the react-native.gradle file

